# Which version of PVZ2 added a 30fps cap?

Tags: android, plants-vs-zombies-2

According to online [forum](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Plants-vs-Zombies-2/Todays-update-capped-the-framerate-to-30fps-instead-of-60fps/m-p/4699953) [posts](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlantsVSZombies/comments/f5sigg/comment/fi0h4sm/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=mweb3x&utm_name=mweb3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), there was an update for Plants vs Zombies 2 for Android back in 2015 that decreased the framerate cap from 60fps to 30fps. What was the version number of the update that added the 30fps cap?

Comment: Apparently a 60fps option was readded recently in the options menu. I'll leave the question as-is.

Comment: Since the forum post is dated July 2015, looking at PVZ2's update history it could be 3.8.1 version.